# git: is it “legal” to add additional subfolders & files to the .git folder?

Tags: git

I’d like to store root certificates with repositories which are used in post-commit and pre-receive hooks.
Obviously they should come from an unrevisioned folder as it must not be possible to check in new trust anchors.
Would behaviour be well defined if I’d add a new folder ‘trustanchors’ in the .git folder and store the certificates there, or is this not allowed with git?

Answer (score 3):

Git itself won't mind if you create files and/or directories within the `.git` directory.  There are a few things to watch out for though:

- Files might be treated as "refs": `HEAD`, `ORIG_HEAD`, `MERGE_HEAD`, and so on are handled by creating or updating files in `.git`.
- Files might be overwritten by other files: e.g., `.git/index` holds Git's main index, and other parts of Git might create various temporary index files with similar names.
- New features in Git will add things.  For instance, when `git worktree` was added to Git, suddenly Git began creating and writing into `.git/worktrees`.

The last one is perhaps the most dangerous.  What if some future Git version decides to use your name, `trustanchors`, for some *other* purpose?  On the other hand, if you get your stuff working nicely and it seems generally applicable, you can contribute it back *to* the Git folks and, in effect, reserve your directory name.  So it might be the biggest danger, but it's also its own best advocate.

Answer (score 2):

My first instinct is to recommend against it, largely for the reasons torek mentions.  Also keep in mind that files under `.git` are not shared automatically by push and fetch, so you'd have to set up each repo individually.  (Depending on how the remote is hosted, it may not have a `.git` directory that you can access.  If it's a simple bare repo, then it kinda-sorta has a `.git` directory...)

On the other hand, if your hooks need data, I guess putting it in a file under the `hooks` directory isn't the worst idea.  It's unlikely git would add a feature that conflicts with that.  And you're already having to distribute the hook scripts themselves (at least for the client-side hooks).

Another idea if you do want the data to be sharable (but still not versioned) would be to store a `BLOB` containing the cert (or even a `TREE` listing `BLOB`s with certs), tag the `BLOB` (or `TREE`) directly, and sign the tag.

Comment: The files not being shared automatically by push and fetch is kinda the point, because you wound’t want people to be able to push new root certificates to the repository (since they decide which commits can be trusted)

Comment: @matthias_buehlmann ok, when you made that argument for why it shouldn't be versioned I was willing to play along, but at this piont you're conflating inconvenience with security.  A signed tag pointing to a `TREE` or `BLOB` is absolutely immutable in spite of being distributable via push and fetch.

Comment: that's true, but what I want is a folder that contains all rootCAs which this client or server considers as being trusted. If it's something that can be pushed/fetched, then new certificates could be placed there via push/fetch, which should not be possible

Comment: @matthias_buehlmann - "a folder that contains all rooCAs which the client or server considers as being trusted" woudl be a `TREE` which you could point to with a signed tag.  That is something that can be pushed/fetched, but as noted above it is absolutely immutable - meaning that no, new certs cannot be placed there via push/fetch.

Comment: but each client/server should still be able to add new trusted CA certificates. so, how would I do that so that I can get the folder containing the currently trusted CA files from a hook, so that each client or server still can add or remove files from that location but they are never pushed/fetched?

Comment: @matthias_buehlmann When someone keeps adding requirements that weren't in the question, I start to think they're really after free consulting work.  Well, no matter your soultion, you're going to need a way to distinguish a valid change (adding a valid cert) from an invalid one (someone trying to inject a bad cert).  So the authority that can make that distinction becomes the signing authority for the tag, and can update the tag/signature when necessary.  But this is only MORE reason why you shouldn't be so fixated on wanting to aviod having an easy way to distribute the certs among repos.

Comment: @matthias_buehlmann ... and btw, I'm not saying that signed tagged objects are teh best way to solve this problem; what I'm saying is, you've expressed that you want to solve the problem within git, and in that case this makes at least as much - and MO more - sense than manually distributing a data file that you'd place in the .git directory.

Answer (score 0):

There's an old convention for local additions: prefix their names with `x-`.

But you don't have to worry quite as much as you once would have about the potential for future name clashes, Git itself has made it easy for just about anyone to correct them.

Regardless, I'd suggest sticking your sideband data in the `info` subdir or maybe make an `x-info` if you want extra purity points, though I've never done that or seen it done, either way using Git's own conventions for environment vars to locate your files, `` stuff=${GIT_DIR-`git rev-parse --absolute-git-dir`}/info `` or some such, then a `mkdir -p "$stuff"` somewhere and `"$stuff"/trustcerts` to refer to the file.