is it safe to add a directory *inside* of the .git/ folder
I am making a git hook that needs to store some metadata about the repo between runs. (more precisely a hook that pre-writes commit messages using an llm, and I need to keep a vector database indexing the code of the repo for RAG).
Right now, that data is stored in an untracked directory at the root of the worktree (repo/.autocommit_storage_dir). This works fine in most usecases, but fails if the repository is a bare repository, or has multiple worktrees.
It would be easier to just store that metadata in the git directory itself (ie repo/.git/autocommit_storage_dir). Is it safe to do so? Will git randomly mess with that directory if I do that?

Answer from empirical knowledge : no problem as long it doesn't have the name of a subdir used by git (which seems good in your case).

Please refer to this I think they summed it up nicely: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66090635/git-is-it-legal-to-add-additional-subfolders-files-to-the-git-folder

An idea specifically tuned for per-hook local data: keep e.g. your pre-commit hook's private data in a .git/hooks/pre-commit.d directory.
